# How can I identify comments associated with a Java class/function?

Tags: java, regex, eclipse, documentation-generation

Firstly I'd like to clarify that I'm not looking for suggestions on existing documentation generators.
My homework assignment is to build a documentation generator ( like a JavaDoc clone ).

Here's what I've done till now :

My first observation was that since the documentation is usually written after a code has been tested it is safe to assume that the code is free from syntactical errors.
Using this observation I created regular expressions to identify class and function declaration statements. From those statements I extracted the groups in the regular expression to get details about the class/function ( for example: Name, inherited classes, return type etc ).

Now here's where I'm stuck. I cannot modify my logic to extract the comments and associate it with the description for the respective class / function for which it was written ( For this purpose I am assuming that the comment describing the behavior is written above the declaration for the class / function ).

I have tried to figure out a way to extend the logic of my program to extract comment descriptions however most opensource tools such as Doclava ( https://code.google.com/p/doclava/ ) are really complex and use some sort of parser and I have no idea what they are or how they work.

Comment: Is this a job or homework assignment?

Comment: This is a homework assignment. Also in response to the moderators I would like to say that the question is not too broad. I just need some modifications in my logic and some reading material on creating eclipse plugins. The question is too long because I wanted to describe exactly what I wanted.

Comment: It is broad as in there are so many different approaches it can get down a rabbit hole quick.

Comment: So any suggestions on how to narrow it down because I didn't even know that there were a lot of approaches to modify an existing regular expression

Comment: Ask about a specific piece you are having trouble with not a whole overview of it

Comment: Thank you for the advice. I hope the question now fits the rules of the forum.